# Display color on different buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I am making a quiz app, and I am using the following code to display to the user if the answer is correct or wrong.

The app looks like this:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7hdy.png)

This is the code to display:

```
@IBAction func checkAnswer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let question = currentQuestion, let answer = sender.titleLabel?.text {
            
            if (question.validateAnswer(to: answer)) {
                score.incrementCorrectAnswers()
                currentScore = currentScore + 1
                feedbackLabel.textColor = UIColor(red:0.15, green:0.61, blue:0.61, alpha:1.0)
                feedbackLabel.text = "Correct!"
                scoreLabel.text = "\(currentScore)"
                
                sender.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "213F4B")
            } else {
                score.incrementIncorrectAnswers()
                feedbackLabel.textColor = UIColor(red:0.82, green:0.40, blue:0.26, alpha:1.0)
                feedbackLabel.text = "Wrong, correct answer is: \n\(currentQuestion!.getAnswer())"
                
                sender.shake()
                
                sender.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "3F2F4B")
                
            }
            answer1Button.isEnabled = false
            answer2Button.isEnabled = false
            answer3Button.isEnabled = false
            answer4Button.isEnabled = false
            nextQuestionButton.isEnabled = true
            
            feedbackLabel.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

When using this, if the user tap the wrong button, the button turns red, and if the user taps the correct button, the button turns green. How can I make it so if the user taps the wrong button, the answer on the correct button turns green at the same time as the wrong one goes red? Let me know if any other code from project is necessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through all `UIButton`'s and check for `sender.titleLabel?.text` like this:

```
for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
    if let btn = view as? UIButton {
        if btn.titleLabel?.text == currentQuestion!.getAnswer() {
            btn.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "213F4B") // Green Color
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not on my computer so won't be able to test it, so try it out and let me know how it works.